# NPM peer dependencies - options for resolution?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

First-off, I am new to NodeJs and NPM so thanks in advance for any clarification that anyone can offer me.

This is a question about peer dependencies and warnings given by NPM during package installs. The NPM docs and other questions on StackOverflow don't seem to answer my exact questions about what I can/should do to resolved these dependency issues.

Actually, Everything I have tried seems to have made things worse I am now completely confused.

Starting from a fresh install of the latest Angular CLI I created a new Angular 5 project. To this I have added Angular Material.

When I added Angular flex-layout I got the following warnings:

```
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10-4905443 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10-4905443 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Adding angular-split adds the following:

```
npm WARN angular-split@0.2.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-split@0.2.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I have done some successful experiments with angular-layout but angular-split does not seem to be working correctly. The examples on the author's website are fine so I suspect that this might be because it doesn't have the Angular version it is expecting.

Do these warnings imply that I can install the required versions of Angular components side-by-side with the primary versions used by my code to satisfy these libraries' requirements?

Alternatively, do they really mean that flex-layout and angular-split are not fully compatible with the version of Angular that I am using (and therefore I can't use them until they are updated).

In summary, can different versions of the same module co-exist in a project, and if so, what steps do I need to take because all I have done so far is get myself in a dreadful mess.

This is what  my packages.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "angular-test4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-split": "^0.2.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think that having multiple versions of the same package is a good idea. I suggest you correct all the dependencies manually make a list and tey to install them.

Comment: Hi  Deepak, That's the nub of my  problem. I have libraries that seem to  want different versions that are lower than the version I  have installed. Does this mean that I have to, in this case, downgrade to  Angular 4.0.0 (ie the lowest common denominator) to satisfy all the dependencies - or is there something else I  should do that I am missing entirely?

Comment: FWIW angular-split seems to work fine if enclosed it in a container with height specified. Things seem to be working but I am still puzzled by these warnings and don't know if I can safely ignore them.